# How do i export a function named 'import' from a module in Perl?

Tags: perl

I've written a special import function that will be used in a few places and I'd like to be able to just go "use ImportRenamer;" in those modules and have them use the import gained from ImportRenamer henceforth. How would i go about that?

Edit: In other words: How do i import 'import' without running it?

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to match what you really want to do. Do you mean to export an 'import' sub, or do you just want 'import' to run automatically in some situations?  DVK's answer answers the second case.

Comment: It's the first case, which is the exact same thing i wrote up there, only with function instead of sub. I'm sorta confused as to how this is unclear. :D

Comment: @mithaldu - OK, just to confirm - do you want to have a sub called "import" in module "ImportRenamer", and (1) NOT run it when you do "use ImportRenamer" in a module called "MyModule1"; and (2) when you do `use MyModule`, it will run `ImportRenamer::import()` instead of `MyModule::import()`?

Comment: @mithaldu: perhaps you can step back and explain what you are hoping to achieve, because you may be selecting the wrong implementation for this.

Comment: @mithaldu - See my update in the answer. And I second Ether's suggestion from last comment

Comment: Oh, I'm completely agreeing that this is entirely the wrong thing to do. And I haven't even told you yet what my import() does. However the right thing is a complete rewrite of a way too big codebase, so for now the wrong thing is what I'll need to do in order to at least move away from worse things. :)

Comment: Man, now i got three right answers and i don't know which one to accept. Thanks guys. :) I think I'll wait for the upvotes to tell me which one SO thinks is the best written one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Now that OP clarified his needs, this should indeed be done in a way similar to what Exported does, to be precise, by injecting the sub reference into a caller's namespace via a glob assignment. Example:

```
###############################################

package ImportRenamer; 
use strict;
sub import_me {
   print "I am a cool importer\n";
}

sub import { 
  my ($callpkg)=caller(0);
  print "Setting ${callpkg}::import to ImportRenamer::import_me\n"; 
  no strict "refs";
  *{$callpkg."::import"} = \&ImportRenamer::import_me; # Work happens here!!!
  use strict "refs";
}
1;

###############################################

package My; 
use strict;
use ImportRenamer; 
1;

###############################################

package My2; 
use strict;
use ImportRenamer; 
1;

###############################################
```

And the test:

```
> perl -e '{  package main; use My; use My2; 1;}'
Setting My::import to ImportRenamer::import_me
I am a cool importer
Setting My2::import to ImportRenamer::import_me
I am a cool importer
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You  don't need to do anything special beyond calling the import method "`import`". `use` already calls `import()`, see [perldoc use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

```
use Module LIST
```

> Imports some semantics into the current package from the named module, 
>   generally by aliasing certain subroutine or variable names into your package.
>
> It is exactly equivalent to:

```
 BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. It seems to me that his problem is more, "How do I hide the build-in `import` with my module?"

Comment: As JSBangs says. Your answer tells me how to *run* import from outside. I want to import 'import'.

Comment: @mithaldu - OK, just to confirm - do you want to have a sub called "import" in module "ImportRenamer", and (1) NOT run it when you do "use ImportRenamer" in a module called "MyModule1"; and (2) when you do `use MyModule`, it will run `ImportRenamer::import()` instead of `MyModule::import()`?

Comment: Correct. I'm not particularly picky what "import" is called in ImportRenamer, but i want to be able to go "use ImportRenamer;" in MyModule, so MyModule::import becomes the function that ImportRenamer exports.

Maybe i should look at how Exporter does it.

Comment: @JSBangs - OK, now I git it. Updated

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a custom `import` method in your module that will export your function you want to be called import in the calling namespace.

Here's some untested code:

```
package ImportMe;

sub import { 

    # Get package name
    my $caller = caller;

    # Install my_import into the calling package as import
    {    no strict 'refs';
         *{"${caller}::import"} = \&my_import;
    }

    return 1;
}

# renamed as import when installing
sub my_import {

   # do stuff

}
```

Now you can put `use ImportMe;` in all your modules and an `import` method will be installed.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can avoid mucking around in the symbol table by using [Sub::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub::Exporter)

```
package Your::Module;

use Sub::Exporter (
    -setup => {
        exports => {
            import => sub { return \&_real_import }
        },
        # the "default" group auto-exports "import" without the caller 
        # specifically asking for it
        groups => { default => [qw(import)] },
    }
);

sub _real_import { ... }
```

**EDIT:**  added the "default" group for auto-exporting

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
package Your::Module;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub import { 
    # gets called by use Your::Module
    my ( $pkg ) = caller;

    no strict 'refs';
    *{ $pkg . '::import' } = \&_real_import;
}

sub _real_import { 
    # import function to be exported to caller
    print "blah blah";
}
```

This manually assigns the `_real_import` sub to the `import` slot of the calling package's namespace. If you do this in a `BEGIN` block, then the `import` sub should be ready and waiting when *that* package gets `use`d.